# When does Winter Bash really end?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2020

I am just wondering what time exactly does the Winter Bash end.

As mentioned in the FAQ [here](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/faq), it says:

> ### What is going on? Why do I see hats?
>
> From December 16th through January 4th, you'll be able to earn hats all over the sites! Ask, answer, vote, edit, and chat, and you'll uncover hats hidden in all kinds of places.

It says:

> From December 16th through January 4th

But it doesn't say the exact time frame.

Does it end of Jan. 4th UTC 00:00 or Jan. 5th UTC 00:00.

I am just wondering because the FAQ page doesn't say it clear.

Comment: There are two "endings", the 'end of awarding' and the 'end of possession'; last year I don't think the time was *exact*, more like 'when the script ran' (like the weekly updating of SEDE's databases) - it's not on/off (binary).

Comment: @Rob Yeah according to the blog it says jan 4 23:59 like in my answer

Comment: Last year, the last post, statistics and mentions, was [Jan **15** 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/15/winter-persists-but-winter-bash-2019-has-drawn-to-a-close/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I now just realized on the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/12/15/hat-season-is-on-its-way-join-us-for-winter-bash-2020/):

> Hat season starts now (December 16, 2020 at midnight UTC) and ends on January 4, 2021 (at 11:59 UTC).

So it virtually ends in January 5th 00:00 UTC time.