# What hour will hats stop?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

As mentioned in the [Winter Bash FAQ](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/faq) page, Winter Bash ends on January 5th...

Is the end of Winter Bash January 5th UTC 23:59? Or January 5th UTC 11:59?

It isn't clear on the FAQ page.

Comment: [Same like last time :P](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359090/when-does-winter-bash-really-end)

Comment: A primary source may be [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/15/millinery-on-the-stack-join-us-for-winter-summer-bash-2021/).

Comment: Last minute efforts to grab some more hats ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Whether you like it hot or you like it cold, enjoy this holiday season with Winter (or is it Summer?) Bash. As you participate on your favorite Stack Exchange sites, you’ll uncover hats that your avatar can wear. Earn the hats listed below ... or do a little extra to find all the secret hats. **The fun ends January 5th at 12:00 UTC.**

It started at 12:00 UTC (noon), and it will end at 12:00 UTC (noon).